# How to send variables from one views to another?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

in my html template I have a variable `{{ student.mail}}` from context in view Nr.1. In this template I also have button `<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'send_and_home' mail=student.mail %}" role="button">Save and Send</a>`. How to send this student.mail to the view Nr.2. The first view returns home page without any . My second page also returns the same home page, but also inside have an additional function to send mail. I don't understand how to implement something like this? Could you help me?

my urls:

```
path('home/', views.home, name="home"),
```

my 1st view:

```
   @login_required(login_url='login')
    def home(request):
        # smth
    
        context = ...
        return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)
```

my 2nd view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def send_and_home(request, mail):
    # article, text, to for mail() depends on mail var from my template
    mail()
    

    context = the same as a view Nr.1
    return render(request, 'app/home.html', context)


def mail(request, article, text, to):
    
    return send_mail(
    article,
    'text',
    '........',
    [to,],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am just add new tag:

```
import re
from django import template
from django.core.mail import send_mail
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def mail(address):
    return send_mail(
    '....',
    'Test 2) ',
    '.....',
    [address,],
    fail_silently=False,
    )
```

And then in template:

```
{% load mail %}
....
{{ var | mail }}
```